# Como jogar esse valor pra um campo input?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou precisando pegar o id de um item da minha lista e preencher o input com esse id. Até agora com algumas pesquisas consegui escolher qual das opções e exibir o id em um alert, mas preciso preencher o input tcod com o valor da id, já tentei com attr e prop mas sem resultado. Poderiam me ajudar ?

```js
$(".tt").click(function() {
  var valor = $(this).parent().parent().find('.tes');
  alert(valor.html());
}
```

```html
<label>Codigo<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="tcod" required>
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `cad` WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%' ";
$ex = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

          
        while($rows = $ex->fetch_array()){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='tes'>".$rows['idcad']." </td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows['nome']." </td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows['nome_mae']." </td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows['idade']." </td>";    
        echo "<nav id='edita'>";     
        echo "<td><i class='fa fa-search tt' id='cod' value=''></i></td>";
        echo "</nav>";

        echo "</tr>";   
        
       
        
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Vc altera o valor de um input com `.val()`. Não pode repetir id's no HTML (`id='cod'`) e por que existe um `</nav>` no meio da tabela?

Comment: O nav foi um dos testes que fiz, porque nas primeiras tentativas estava lançando o valor dentro do input porém somente da ultima opção, pode ser retirado do código, mas eu tentei colocar assim :                                   
        <script type="text/javascript">  
           $(".tt").click(function() {
            var valor = $(this).parent().parent().find('.tes');
            $("input[name='tcod']").val(valor);
         
});
        </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note que o input que você quer preencher é do tipo `number`, portanto só vai aceitar números. Caso o id que você queira pegar e jogar no campo não seja um número, o campo ficará vazio e será mostrado um aviso no console do navegador.

Para pegar o texto da célula `.tes` da mesma linha do botão clicado, você usa `.closest("tr")` para achar a linha do botão, e depois o `.find(".tes")` para achar a célula. Use o `.text()` para pegar o texto dentro da célula e `.trim()` para limpar possíveis espaços antes e depois do texto. Em seguida use `.val()` para alterar o valor do input.

Não precisa usar `.parent()` 2 vezes. O `.closest()` já vai direto ao elemento pai onde você quer chegar. Veja:

```js
$(".tt").click(function() {
  var valor = $(this).closest("tr").find('.tes');
   $("[name='tcod']").val(valor.text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<label>Codigo<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="tcod" required>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td class='tes'>1</td>
      <td>nome1</td>
      <td>nome mãe 1</td>
      <td>18 anos</td>
      <td>
         <i class='fa fa-search tt' id='cod' value=''></i>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class='tes'>2</td>
      <td>nome2</td>
      <td>nome mãe 2</td>
      <td>20 anos</td>
      <td>
         <i class='fa fa-search tt' id='cod' value=''></i>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo ! Funcionou certinho da forma que queria , me ajudou muito, sou grato .

Answer (score 0):

Na bem verdade essa pergunta não deveria estar tagueada com o PHP.

Mas se o que deseja é setar o id do input use:

```
$(".tt").click(function() {
  var valor = $(this).parent().parent().find('.tes');
   /* define o valor do input name=tcod */
  $('input[name="tcod"]').attr("id", valor.html() );
}
```

Se deseja setar o valor do input name="tcod", seria só usar:

```
$(".tt").click(function() {
  var valor = $(this).parent().parent().find('.tes');
   /* define o valor do input name=tcod */
  $('input[name="tcod"]').val(valor.html());
}
```

Comment: Então , a tag do php realmente foi desnecessária, na próxima pergunta irei prestar mais atenção. Mas tentei da forma que você descreveu e não deu certo, clico no icone para chamar a função e nada acontece.Meu codigo ficou assim:                                    
        
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        
           $(".tt").click(function() {
            var valor = $(this).parent().parent().find('.tes');
            $("input[name='tcod']").val(valor.html());
});